# Absulute value of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, operator-theory

Suppose V is an finite dimensional inner product space.

For $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, define $|T|=\sqrt{T^*T}$.

This definition is analogous to the absolutely value of real numbers, so I am wondering if $||T||=|T|$ holds (note that $||T||$ is not operator norm but rather the composition of two $|\cdot|$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.  Note that $||T||$ is the unique positive semidefinite square root of the positive semidefinite matrix $|T|^* |T| = |T|^2 = T^* T$, 
and that square root is $|T|$ itself.

Comment: How does one get $|T|^*|T|=|T|^2$, I think I'm missing something here. Is it somehow related to the $C^*$ identity?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized that $|T|$ is positive hence self-adjoint. Thanks!